# Need help to write a function to find max and min value in a N-dimensional array C++

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, sorting, vector

I need to find max and min value of a array in different dimensions(will be 1-d, 2-d and up to N dimension array) in my program.

Can anyone help me to write a function or function template that can take input of an arbitrary dimension array and find the max/min value?
* I'm using vector of vectors
Something like this:

```
#include <vector>
    <template T>
int find_max(T target_array, int dimension);
int main() {
    using namespace std;
    vector<int> array_1d = {1,3,4};
    vector<vector<int> array_2d = {{1,3},{3,5,2},{6,4}};
    vector<vector<vector<int>>> array_3d = {{{1,3},{2,4,5}},{{6,7,2,3}}};
    cout << "Max in 1d array: " << find_max<vector<int>>(array_1d, 1) << endl;
    cout << "Max in 2d array: " << find_max<vector<vector<int>>(array_2d, 2) << endl;
    cout << "Max in 3d array: " << find_max<vector<vector<vector<int>>>>(array_3d, 3) << endl;  
    return 0;          
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
Max in 1d array: 4
Max in 2d array: 6
Max in 3d array: 7
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Thank you

Comment: `vector<vector<int>>` should not be used as a 2-dimensional array. If you keep your elements in contiguous memory like you should you can just use [`std::minmax_element`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/minmax_element).

Comment: Arrays or vectors? Vectors of vectors may not even have same depths on every subdimension ie {{1,2,3},{3,5},{6}}

Comment: Hi Snpa,I don't know how to use 1 function to deal with different input, what i'm doing now is write different functions for different dimensions...

Comment: Hi Cristian Niculescu, yeah that's the problem and make me headache it's vector of vectors and it has deferent depth.....

Comment: Hi nwp, how about 2+ dimensions? what data structure should i use

Comment: Using `vector<vector<int>>` as a 2-D array is OK. Whether it is *optimal* depends on what you will be doing with it. The main advantage of it is that it is very simple and clear to use.

Comment: @CharlesChow I accidentally replied to you but I wanted to reply to Cristian Niculescu. Let me try again :)

Comment: @CristianNiculescu Why should this be a problem? You mean they don't have the same size on every subdimension. They do have the same depth though.

Comment: Regarding your edit: You don't need to provide the template type if it can be deduced from the function argument, which it can in this case.

Comment: @leemes I was pointing out that if same size on every element of subdimension, data can easily be rrpresented in arrays instead of vectors. As it stands, I'm clueless as to how to address this without something like RTTI and autos under C++11.

Comment: hi @Cristian Niculescu , do you think i can use a recursive call to dig the data structure to the deepest layer(vector<int>). than find the value i need? like expand a tree or perform a breadth first search or depth first search?

Comment: Charles Chow yes that is possible. The answer from @leemes does a depth first search. Note that your tree only stores values in leafs. So breadth first would only apply to the last level of your tree. It will need a depth first search to extract all leafs into a temp vector<int> and then one search on that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another minimal example of how it can be done:

```
int find_max(int i) {
    return i;
}

template <typename T>
int find_max(const std::vector<T>& v) {
    return std::accumulate(std::begin(v), std::end(v),
        std::numeric_limits<int>::min(),
        [] (const int prev, const T& v) {
            int m = find_max(v);
            return (m > prev) ? m : prev;
        });
}
```

This will work with an arbitrary level of nested `std::vector`s.

<kbd>[**Live example**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1d904297f47fd6a0)</kbd>

### Edit:

See the updated code (changed return statement inside the lambda). Previous version did not work correctly with negative numbers.

Answer (score 5):

The function you wrote the signature of can be implemented with a simple call to `std::max_element`.

Then you can overload this function with a template accepting *any nested vector*, which first recursively applies the function to each element of the vector before computing the maximum value of them.

The following code implements this idea. The second parameter `int dimension` is not required, since the number of dimensions is given by the type of the first parameter.

If you want both min and max elements simultaneously, you could use something like `std::minmax_element` for the base case, but the recursive call gets way more complicated then.

**Live demo: http://ideone.com/kW0ewz**

```
// Forward-declare
template<class T>
int find_max(std::vector<std::vector<T> > target_array);

// First, define the base case
int find_max(std::vector<int> target_array) {
    using namespace std;

    return *max_element(
        target_array.begin(),
        target_array.end());
}

// Then the general case
template<class T>
int find_max(std::vector<std::vector<T> > target_array) {
    using namespace std;

    // Reserve a vector for the recursive call
    vector<int> reduced(target_array.size());

    // Recursively apply this function to each nested vector
    transform(
        target_array.begin(),
        target_array.end(),
        reduced.begin(),
        [](std::vector<T> v){ return find_max(v); });

    // Then find the maximum of the reduced vector
    return *max_element(
        reduced.begin(),
        reduced.end());
}
```

Comment: While this is elegant and good in homework settings, note that using this against a matrix of N dimensions will auto-generate N find_max function implementations. Use with care in production code.

Comment: Thank you leemes! I just learned how to use `std::transform` from your example!

Comment: @CristianNiculescu Why should that be a problem? As long as `N` is a low number, and I mean something below 100 maybe, it's not going to blow up your program, neither in experimental nor production use. (I mean, 100 dimensional vector... Note that a matrix always has 2 dimensions. Again, don't confuse dimension with size.)

Answer (score 3):

Be aware that templated functions can derive their argument types.  You don't need to specify the types to call the methods; and you can have them drive their call parameters for you (same isn't true for template structures).  You can exploit that.

Here's another solution:

```
int find_max(int a) { return a; } // Just a base case for recursion
template<typename T>
int find_max(const std::vector<T>& v)
{
   int r = find_max(v.front());
   for (auto i=v.begin()+1, e=end()
       ; i<e
       ; ++i)
   {
      int c = find_max(*i);
      if (c>r) r=c;
   }
   return r;
}
```

The usage is the same regardless of how many nested vectors you have:

```
cout << "Max in 1d array: " << find_max(array_1d) << endl;
cout << "Max in 2d array: " << find_max(array_2d) << endl;
cout << "Max in 3d array: " << find_max(array_3d) << endl;
```

...the STL approach is more focused on giving you the maximum T in a container of T; if we're nesting T's, we have to recurse twice to get the root element's out (one to tell us which T has the max value, and again to extract it).  The approach here is simple bottom up recursion (each find_max gives you the largest value of that level structure, and we just trickle out).